# If $g(x)=f(x)+f(1-x)$ and $f'(x)<0$ then $g$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let , $g(x)=f(x)+f(1-x)$ and $f'(x)<0$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. Then , $g$ is monotone increasing in

(A) $(1/2,1)$.

(B) $(0,1/2)$

(C) $(0,1/2)\cup (1/2,1)$.

(D) none.

We have , $g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(1-x)$. Now $g'(x)>0$ if $f'(x)>f'(1-x)$. As $f'(x)<0$ so , $f$ is monotone decreasing in $(0,1)$. From here how I can conclude ?

Comment: Hint: what happens if $f(x) = -x$?

Comment: Presumably, you mean "$g$ is monotone increasing **in**."

Comment: What is the exact phrasing of the question? Because I think the answer should be "unable to determine." "None" is a confusing answer for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_1(x)=-x^2$. Then $f_1'(x)=-2x<0$ and $g_1(x)=-x^2-(1-x))^2 = -2x^2+2x-1$ and $g_1'(x)=2-4x$ so $g(x)$ is decreasing when $x>\frac{1}{2}$.

On the other hand, if $f_2(x)=(1-x)^2$. Then $f_2'(x)=-2(1-x)<0$ and $g_2(x)=(1-x)^2+x^2=-g_1(x)$. So $g_2(x)$ is increasing precisely where $g_1(x)$ was not, and visa versa.

Therefore, it is not possible to determine where $g$ is increasing/decreasing. I don't feel like "none" is the right answer, but it would depend on the precise phrasing of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Can u conclude this inequality???
$$f(\frac{2}{8})+f(\frac{6}{8})<f(\frac{1}{8})+f(\frac{7}{8}) $$
So $D$ is the answer.

Comment: This is what we call "proof by assertion."

Comment: Definitely yes.